# Find eigenvector without using characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1&1\\2&1&-2&1\\-1&1&1&1\\2&-2&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Without computing the characteristic polynomial of $A$, find all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $(1, 1, 1, a)$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

How shall I proceed here? Thank you for any hint / help.

Comment: You should edit in your own efforts too

Comment: Did you try applying definition ?

Comment: You mean looking for eigenvalues?

Comment: Solve the equation $AX_a=\lambda_a X_a$. You will need to find the possible values for $\lambda_a$ and $X_a$ that fullfill this equality.

Comment: It's true that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\lambda$ to be an eigen value of the matrix $A$. But a more fundamental statement is that for a given linear transformation $T$, a non-zero vector $v\in V$ is an eigen vector for  the transformation if there exist a $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$. Take $T:V\to V$ to be $T(x)=Ax$. Using this you have a scalor $\lambda$ is an eigen value of transformation iff $\ker(T-\lambda I)$ is non trivial. I is the identity transformation. This actually gives rise to the notion of characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Ah thank you! Such a fundamental thing, I am studying this on my own so it is kinda confusing sometimes, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v=(1,1,1,a)^{T}$.
Then

$Av = (a+1,a+1,a+1,0)^{T}$

If $\lambda$ is the eigen value corresponding to eigen vector $v$.

$\lambda v= (\lambda,\lambda,\lambda,a\lambda)^{T}$.

Then you have $\lambda = a+1$ and $a\lambda =0$.

So if $a=0$ then  $\lambda=1$ is an eigen value for which $(1,1,1,a)^{T}=(1,1,1,0)^T$ is an eigen vector.

If $a\neq 0$ . Then $\lambda =0$ and $a=-1$.

So for eigen value $1$ , $(1,1,1,a)^{T}$ is an eigen vector for $a=0$.

And for eigen value $0$ , the vector $(1,1,1,a)^{T}$ is an eigen vector for $a=-1$.